# target="new" is not opening new tab or window of my browser in OpenSocial app

Tags: html, open-source, web-standards

`target="new"` is not opening new tab or window of my browser in OpenSocial app!

Answer (score 4):

```
target="_blank"
```

Answer (score 2):

`target="new"` ins't valid HTML

Use `target="_blank"` instead.

Comment: I thought `target="new"` would open a new window if one named "new" didn't already exist. But that might be 4.0-era behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're talking about an anchor tag, so make that `target="_blank"`

Comment: No both of the above solutions doesnt work!

Comment: Then show your code. It absolutely *does* work if you're using anchor tags. Everyone here has given you the same answer, so either your question is incomplete or misleading or else we're all just dunces. The over/under is not in your favor on this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` should work
- unless you have a some software running which is preventing a pop up to be opened...

Answer (score 0):

The:

`...target="Troy III">`

Will open the link in a new TAB instead of a window by default on the following popular browsers: Firefox; Chrome; Opera; but not in IE and Safari